# Similar slide Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullpage.js

Is it possible to set two sections with same slide? Like if i'm on (section 1 slide 1) then i move (to section 1 slide 2), section 2 will set slide 2.

I'm wondering if this is possible in fullpage.js

I would like to create similar to this.
[jsfiddle.net/7p927/](http://jsfiddle.net/7p927)

```
 <div class="section" id="first">
   <div class="slide">1</div>
   <div class="slide">2</div>
   <div class="slide">3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="second">
   <div class="slide">1</div>
   <div class="slide">2</div>
   <div class="slide">3</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible right now. But you can take a look at some modifications which you could do in the plugin to achieve it.

Take a look at this answer:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/129#issuecomment-30747985

Then you could call that function in some callback such as `afterSlideLoad`.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question. Is it possible to change slide transition to fade?

Comment: @timmy no it's not. This is an scrolling plugin.